# Stop all audio when a new one is playing

Tags: javascript, audio, onclick, playlist

I'm trying to code a playlist.
I'd like to start an audio when the title of the audio is clicked.
For now it works, but when I click a title and then others, previous songs clicked are not stopped so they are all playing at the same time.
Here is my html :

```
     <div class="audio" onclick=
      "playAudio('algebrasuicide_fathersbythedoor.wav')">
      algebra suicide father by the door 
     </div>
  
  
     <div class="audio"onclick=
     "playAudio('algebrasuicide_inbedwithboys.wav')">
     algebra suicide in bed with boys 
     </div>
     

     <div class="audio"onclick=
     "playAudio('aprilmagazine_parade.wav')">
     april magazine parade
     </div>
```

and this is my js :

```
function playAudio(src) {
  new Audio(src).play();
}
```

I'm a novice, I know the answer is probably very simple but I tried a lot of things and nothing worked.

I hope someone here can help me !
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest would be to keep a reference to the current audio (if any) and `.pause()` it.

```js
let audio;

function pauseAudio() {
  // If audio is not undefined and if is playing, pause it
  if (audio && !audio.paused) {
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0; // Rewind track to beginning (is you need this)
  }
}

function playAudio(src) {
  pauseAudio();             // Pause any currently playing
  audio = new Audio();      // Save a reference
  audio.src = src;
  audio.play();
}
```

Also, stop using inline JS `on*` handlers in HTML. JavaScript should be in one place only and that's its respective tag of file.

Instead:

```html
<button type="button" data-audio="lorem.wav">Lorem</button>
<button type="button" data-audio="ipsum.wav">Ipsum</button>
<button type="button" data-audio="dolor.wav">Dolor</button>
```

```js
let audio;

function pauseAudio() {
  // If audio is not undefined and if is playing, pause it
  if (audio && !audio.paused) {
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0; // Rewind track to beginning (is you need this)
  }
}

function playAudio(src) {
  pauseAudio();             // Pause any currently playing
  audio = new Audio();      // Save a reference
  audio.src = src;
  audio.play();
}

document.querySelectorAll("[data-audio]").forEach((elAudioBtn) => {
  const src = elAudioBtn.dataset.audio;
  playAudio(src);
});
```

Find out more about: [data-* attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works very well ! and thanks for the comments, helps me understand better :)

Answer (score 0):

Just this?

```js
var audio_;

function playAudio(src) {
    if(audio_) audio_.pause();
    const audio = audio_ = new Audio(src);
    audio.play();
}
```

```html
     <div class="audio" onclick=
      "playAudio('algebrasuicide_fathersbythedoor.wav')">
      algebra suicide father by the door 
     </div>
  
  
     <div class="audio"onclick=
     "playAudio('algebrasuicide_inbedwithboys.wav')">
     algebra suicide in bed with boys 
     </div>
     

     <div class="audio"onclick=
     "playAudio('aprilmagazine_parade.wav')">
     april magazine parade
     </div>
```